# ARM NEON: Load a 64bit int constant

Tags: assembly, arm, simd, neon

I want to load a 64bit unsigned integer constant from the literal pool into register D0 by using the ARM NEON pseudo instruction VLDR:

```
VLDR.U64 D0, =0x50A28BE600000000
```

If I compile, the assembler says:

```
gcc -g -Wall -mfpu=neon -mcpu=cortex-a7 -c ripemd160NEON.s -o ripemd160NEON.o
ripemd160NEON.s: Assembler messages:
ripemd160NEON.s:146: Error: floating point number invalid
```

Why is the hexadecimal value considered to be a floating point number?

Comment: Which version of the GNU assembler are you using?

Comment: `as -v` says "GNU assembler version 2.25 (arm-linux-gnueabihf) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Raspbian) 2.25"

Comment: No repro with binutils 2.27 (assembles to a 64-bit literal load as expected). 2.24, on the other hand, gives the even less specific "Error: invalid constant -- \`vldr.u64 D0,=0x50A28BE600000000'"; oddly it _will_ accept a 32-bit constant, e.g. `vldr.u64 D0,=0x50A28BE6`, but silently misassembles it to `vldr d0, [r0]`. In my experience, why GAS considers anything to be anything is generally a mystery to everyone.

Comment: @Notlikethat, I've investigated that one before and found it was a dodgy backport to a Debian branch. IIRC, The fsf release of 2.24 rejects the syntax, and the fsf 2.25 gets it right.